# Calculus fins rate of change

Tags: calculus

Question:
The total surface area S of a cone of base radius (r) and perpendicular height (h) is given by the following equation:

$$S = \pi r^2 + \pi r \sqrt{r^2+h^2}$$

If (r) and (h) are each increasing at the rate of 0.25cm/sec, find the rate of change that S is increasing at the instant when r = 6cm and h = 8cm, expressing your answer in cm^2 per second.

$$S=πr√((r^2+h^2))+πr^2 , dr/dt=0.25 cm/s, dh/dt=0.25 cm/s$$

$$dS/dt={(πr)*[1/2 (r^2+h^2 )^(-1/2) (2r)+√((r^2+h^2 ) )*(π)]+2πr} dr/dt +{πr*[1/2 (r^2+h^2 )^(-1/2)*(2h)]} dh/dt$$
$$=[(2πr^2)/(2√((r^2+h^2)))+π√((r^2+h^2 ) )+2πr] dr/dt+ (2πrh/(2√((r^2+h^2)))) dh/dt$$
$$=((πr^2)/√((r^2+h^2))+π√((r^2+h^2 ) )+2πr)*0.25+(πrh/√((r^2+h^2)))*0.25$$
$$= ((π6^2)/√((6^2+8^2))+π√((6^2+8^2 ) )+2π6)*0.25+((π6*8)/√((6^2+8^2)))*0.25$$
$$= (π36/√((36+64))+π√((36+64) )+12π)*0.25+(48π/√((36+64)))*0.25$$
$$=(π36/10+10π+12π)*0.25+(48π/10)*0.25$$
$$=(3.6π+10π+12π)*0.25+(4.8π)* 0.25$$

$$= π(25.6 cm)*0.25cm/s + 3.77 〖cm〗^2/s$$
$$= 20.106〖cm〗^2/s +3.77〖cm〗^2/s=23.876 〖cm〗^2/s$$

Comment: Your attempt may benefit from some formatting

Comment: Is it not easy to understand? But this is the correct answer, and the calculations do make sense.

Comment: Absolutely, it is correct. Take a look at my formatting in my solution. The dot notation may make it easier to understand your solution.

Comment: As well as more usage of the frac and sqrt commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take a time derivative of $S$ we have

$$\dot{S} = 2 \pi r \dot{r} + \pi \dot{r} \sqrt{r^2 + h^2} + \frac{ \pi r}{2} \left(r^2 + h^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} (2r \dot{r} + 2h \dot{h})$$

where the dot notation refers to the time derivative of that variable. Since $\dot{r} = \dot{h} = \frac{1}{4} \mathrm{\frac{cm}{s}}$ at our point of interest we have

$$\dot{S} =  2 (6) \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{(6)^2 + (8)^2} + \pi (6) \left((6)^2 + (8)^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)(6 + 8) = 7.6 \pi \mathrm{\frac{{cm}^2}{s}} $$

Answer (score 0):

Exercise:

$dS/dt=$

$2πr(dr/dt)+$

$π(dr/dt)\sqrt{r^2+h^2}+$

$πr\dfrac{r(dr/dt)+h(dh/dt)}{\sqrt{r^2+h^2}}.$